# add texbox values to gridview row in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, linq

```
int Row=0;
Row = PurchaseGridView.Rows.Count;
PurchaseGridView.Rows[Row].Cells[0].Text = ProductNameDropDown.SelectedValue.ToString();
PurchaseGridView.Rows[Row].Cells[1].Text = ProductNameDropDown.SelectedIndex.ToString();
PurchaseGridView.Rows[Row].Cells[2].Text = ProductPriceTxtBox.Text;
PurchaseGridView.Rows[Row].Cells[3].Text = QuantityTxtBox.Text;
PurchaseGridView.Rows[Row].Cells[4].Text = NetPriceTxtBox.Text;
```

i am adding values of textboxes in gridview like above, but it gives error.

Error: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index

Comment: What have you tried? Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: And i want a new car. After that a new house. But SO is not a code writing service. What have you tried? If you are stuck somewhere we can help you.

Comment: i Added code now please guide me.

Comment: You will get that error if there are no rows in `PurchaseGridView`, or if there are less than 5 columns.

Comment: Yes there are no rows, how can i solve this problem.

Comment: or is there any other way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few fundamental errors in your code:

1. You are using the `Count` to point to a new index which doesn't exists and thus you are getting the index out of range.
2. You cannot add rows to an asp.net gridview directly. You have to do it through a data binding. Here is an example:

   ```
   DataTable dt = new DataTable();
   DataColumn dc = new DataColumn("ProductNameSelectedValue", typeof(string));
   DataColumn dc = new DataColumn("ProductNameSelectedIndex", typeof(int));
   ..
   Rest of you columns
   ..

   DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
   dr["ProductNameSelectedValue"] = ProductNameDropDown.SelectedValue.ToString();
   dr["ProductNameSelectedIndex"] = ProductNameDropDown.SelectedIndex;
   ..
   Assign the rest of the columns
   ..

   dt.Rows.Add(dr);

   gv.DataSource = dt;
   gv.DataBind();
   ```

Comment: Every time i call this code it adds new row in grid view but previous data is gone. how can i save previous records and then save new record next to the previous one's.

Comment: You will have to store the datatable as field in your class, initialize it somewhere (ctor maybe), and only the addition of the rows keep in this method